# Nodes lying on Same Path in Trees

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Given a Treen with $n$ nodes and $n-1$ edges, I have to answer $Q$ queries.
In every query, I get a list of nodes of size $k$, $n_1, n_2, ..., n_k$. I need to answer the minimum number of paths that are required that cover all of these nodes.[image: See the example for better insight]

Comment: So if I get the question right, you need to know how many (not necessarily disjoint) paths might be needed to cover $k$ labels in a tree, right?  If so, $k/2$ is always feasible, since each pair of vertices is connected.  And $k/2$ is a worst case when each label appears at a leaf.

Comment: @ManuelLafond yes.

Comment: Then $k/2$ is your answer I believe.